# Junit4 @RunWith multiple runners

Tags: junit, junit4

I have a test class that I am writing and currently it has the below annotation
`@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` because I am injecting dependencies as Mocks using mockito.

I want to test my class with 3 different sets of parameters. How do I achieve having adding `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` along with the `MockitoJUnitRunner.class`?

I tried finding resources online but I did not get anything useful that I can do.